# COM port becomes busy at seemingly random times

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port, led

I am making a c# program that sends LED lighting instructions to a sparkfun pro micro. It generally works at first, but has a chance to fail upon changing one of the color sliders, leaving the com port busy and unusable until I disconnect the pro micro and reupload its code to it

I have tried to close the port in my catch statement but It doesn't seem to help at all (actually made things worse I think). I'm not sure if my serial port class is the issue or the pro micro code is so I'll post both

First, the serial port class. This is run on the Scroll event for each trackbar:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace LED_Controller
{
    public class SerialPortsAccess
    {
        public string testString;

        private SerialPort port;// = new SerialPort("COM6", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

        [STAThread]
        static void createNew(string[] args)
        {
            //new SerialPortsAccess("COM3");
        }

        public SerialPortsAccess(string COM)
        {
            string[] lastInfo = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Alex\source\repos\LED Controler\LED Controler\Last.txt");
            string stringout = "";
            port = new SerialPort(COM, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            try
            {
                port.Open();

                for (int i = 0; i < lastInfo.Length; i++)
                {
                    //port.WriteLine(lastInfo[i]);
                    stringout += lastInfo[i];
                    if ((i + 1) < lastInfo.Length)
                    {
                        stringout += '|';
                    }
                }

                stringout += '\n';
                port.Write(stringout);
                Debug.WriteLine(stringout);
                port.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                //try
                //{
                    //port.Close();
                //}
                //catch
                //{

                //}
                Debug.WriteLine("NO DEVICE FOUND");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is my arduino code. It is long, but the majority of the getData() function is repeating the same process for each variable (I am new to this so my technique is probably pretty bad):

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_DotStar.h>

#define NUMPIXELS 60

Adafruit_DotStar strip = Adafruit_DotStar(NUMPIXELS, DOTSTAR_BRG);

// Variables
int mode;
int numColors;
int fadeSpeed;
int BBCC;
int R;
int G;
int B;
int Bright;

int readLine(int readch, char * buffer, int len)
{
  static int pos = 0;
  int rpos;

  if (readch > 0)
  {
    switch(readch)
    {
      case '\r':
      {
        break;
      }
      case '\n':
      {
        rpos = pos;
        pos = 0;
        return rpos;
      }
      default:
      {
        if (pos < len-1) 
        {
          buffer[pos++] = readch;
          buffer[pos] = 0;
        }
      }
  }

  return 0;
}
}

void loop() {
  getData();


  if (mode == 1)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMPIXELS; i++)
    {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, G, R, B);
    }
    strip.setBrightness(Bright);
    strip.show();
  }
  else
  {
    strip.setPixelColor(0, 255, 255, 255);
    strip.setBrightness(25);
    strip.show();
  }
}

void getData()    // this function has a do while loop for each variable. Sorry if this is bad form
{
  char buf[80];
  bool redo = true;

  if(readLine(Serial.read(), buf, 80) > 0)
  {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    bool skip = false;
    char fin[3];
    if (skip == false)
    {
    do//                                mode
    {
      switch (buf[i])
      {
        case '\n':
        {
          skip = true;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        case '|':
        {
          mode = atoi(fin);
          //Serial.print(mode);
          i++;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        default:
        {
          fin[j] = buf[i];
          i++;
          break;
        }
      }
      j++;
    }while(redo);
    redo = true;
    j = 0;
    }



    if (skip == false)
    {
    do//                     number of colors
    {
      switch (buf[i])
      {
        case '\n':
        {
          skip = true;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        case '|':
        {
          numColors = atoi(fin);
          //Serial.print(numColors);
          i++;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        default:
        {
          fin[j] = buf[i];
          i++;
          break;
        }
      }
      j++;
    }while(redo);
    redo = true;
    j = 0;
    }



    if (skip == false)
    {
    do//                            
    {
      switch (buf[i])
      {
        case '\n':
        {
          skip = true;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        case '|':
        {
          fadeSpeed = atoi(fin);
          //Serial.print(fadeSpeed);
          i++;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        default:
        {
          fin[j] = buf[i];
          i++;
          break;
        }
      }
      j++;
    }while(redo);
    redo = true;
    j = 0;
    }



    if (skip == false)
    {
    do
    {
      switch (buf[i])
      {
        case '\n':
        {
          skip = true;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        case '|':
        {
          BBCC = atoi(fin);
          //Serial.print(BBCC);
          i++;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        default:
        {
          fin[j] = buf[i];
          i++;
          break;
        }
      }
      j++;
    }while(redo);
    redo = true;
    j = 0;
    }



    if (skip == false)
    {
    do
    {
      switch (buf[i])
      {
        case '\n':
        {
          skip = true;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        case '|':
        {
          R = atoi(fin);
          //Serial.print(R);
          i++;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        default:
        {
          fin[j] = buf[i];
          i++;
          break;
        }
      }
      j++;
    }while(redo);
    redo = true;
    j = 0;
    }



    if (skip == false)
    {
    do
    {
      switch (buf[i])
      {
        case '\n':
        {
          skip = true;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        case '|':
        {
          G = atoi(fin);
          //Serial.print(G);
          i++;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        default:
        {
          fin[j] = buf[i];
          i++;
          break;
        }
      }
      j++;
    }while(redo);
    redo = true;
    j = 0;
    }



    if (skip == false)
    {
    do
    {
      switch (buf[i])
      {
        case '\n':
        {
          skip = true;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        case '|':
        {
          B = atoi(fin);
          //Serial.print(B);
          i++;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        default:
        {
          fin[j] = buf[i];
          i++;
          break;
        }
      }
      j++;
    }while(redo);
    redo = true;
    j = 0;
    }



    if (skip == false)
    {
    do
    {
      switch (buf[i])
      {
        case '\n':
        {
          Bright = atoi(fin);
          //Serial.println(Bright);
          i++;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        default:
        {
          fin[j] = buf[i];
          i++;
          break;
        }
      }
      j++;
    }while(redo);
    redo = true;
    j = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

The c# code is supposed to send the data to the form once per track bar change, then close the port until another change is made. The pro micro is supposed to receive the code and interpret it. Somewhere in this process, though, the connection is broken and will not re-establish. What is going wrong here?

EDIT: I tried to use the data recieved event, but now the port won't even open. because the access is denied. Am I using it wrong? New c# code is below:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace LED_Controller
{
    public class SerialPortsAccess
    {
        public string testString;
        bool fail = false;
        private SerialPort port;// = new SerialPort("COM6", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

        [STAThread]
        static void createNew(string[] args)
        {
            //new SerialPortsAccess("COM3");
        }

        public SerialPortsAccess(string COM)
        {
            port = new SerialPort(COM, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

            port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

            //try
            //{
                port.Open();
            //}
            //catch
            //{
                //Debug.WriteLine("ERROR OPENING PORT");
            //}
        }
        public void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] lastInfo = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Alex\source\repos\LED Controler\LED Controler\Last.txt");
            string stringout = "";
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    //port.Open();

                    for (int i = 0; i < lastInfo.Length; i++)
                    {
                        //port.WriteLine(lastInfo[i]);
                        stringout += lastInfo[i];
                        if ((i + 1) < lastInfo.Length)
                        {
                            stringout += '|';
                        }
                    }

                    stringout += '\n';
                    port.Write(stringout);
                    Debug.WriteLine(stringout);
                    port.Close();
                }
                catch
                {
                    fail = true;
                    Debug.WriteLine("DEVICE LOST");
                    port.Close();
                }
            } while (fail == false);//port.BytesToRead != 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using Synchronous Serial.read() is known to read unevenly.  It is better to use Asynchronous methods.  The synchronous reads are blocked by other processes on the machine while Asynchronous reads uses events which do not get blocked when other processes are running.

Comment: is there an asynchronous Serial.read() equivalent? I'm having a hard time finding one

Comment: See on following msdn page Events DataReceived : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I'm confused. So is my Arduino code ok, but my Serial port class is the problem? Or is it the other way around? Also, wouldn't the DataRecieved event be for if I was sending data to my C# program, or should I add a DataRecieved event to my pro micro code?

Comment: Neither.  Your machine is multi-processor and running other processes in parallel with your code.  You are getting receive data and not processing due other app running.   So you get a backlog in your receive buffer that creates the random timing.  Using Async (Events) allows you app to process the received data more evenly.

Comment: So I just need the DataRecieved event handler and I'm good?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197801/discussion-between-boathouse-and-jdweng).

Comment: You should read from the file only once.  You should not close the port and that is why you are getting the error.  The open has to be before your register the event "+=".

Comment: the DataRecieved event is not running. I tested it with breakpoints and none of them fired off. I also confirmed that the port is being opened only once

Comment: The application is closing before you ever read data.  You need to add a block to code so it doesn't terminate.  Simplest method is to put a Console.Readline() after you open the port.

Comment: I don't know if the DataRecieved event is the way to go. I tried putting readline after the port open and it still didn't run the event. I also tried placing the port.open and console.readline after the DataRecieved event just to make sure and it didn't run there either. Is there a "dataSent" event? there is no data being recieved by this code

Comment: Most devices will not start sending until commanded.  You can just write without any events.  There is a write buffer in windows and in c# you are just writing to the buffer.  So the write doesn't wait for the data to be sent (just copied to window buffer) and therefor an event is not necessary.

Comment: I really don't understand. I thought you said in an earlier comment that I needed events in order to Async. Can you please explain in more detail why this isnt working? With my original code, I was able to get my LEDs to light up for a while AND change color as I moved the sliders on the GUI. Now nothing happens at all

Comment: I 'm guessing you are using a serial port to USB adapter right? is it plugged in the same USB port as last time? the COM# can change if the adapter is plugged in a different USB port. You can see the COM# in the device manager.

Comment: I always plug into the same USB port. As far as I know, the COM# isn't changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked through the example code for the Adafruit dotstar example code that was provided with the library and found that it may have been the number of LEDs I tried to run without refreshing the strip. When I mixed my code with the example I was able to run about 30 LEDs without a problem. Anything more would cause the board to go into a fail mode and the COM port would be inaccessible again

Here is the new code:

```
#include <Adafruit_DotStar.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#define NUMPIXELS 60
#define DATAPIN    4
#define CLOCKPIN   5

Adafruit_DotStar strip(NUMPIXELS, DOTSTAR_BRG);

// Variables
int mode;
int numColors;
int fadeSpeed;
int BBCC;
int R;
int G;
int B;
int Bright;

void setup() {

#if defined(__AVR_ATtiny85__) && (F_CPU == 16000000L)
  clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1); // Enable 16 MHz on Trinket
#endif

  strip.begin(); // Initialize pins for output
  strip.show();  // Turn all LEDs off ASAP
}

// Runs 10 LEDs at a time along strip, cycling through red, green and blue.
// This requires about 200 mA for all the 'on' pixels + 1 mA per 'off' pixel.

int      head  = 0, tail = -10; // Index of first 'on' and 'off' pixels
uint32_t color = 0xFFFFFF;      // 'On' color (starts red)

void loop() {

  //strip.setPixelColor(head, color); // 'On' pixel at head
  //strip.setPixelColor(tail, 0);     // 'Off' pixel at tail
  strip.show();                     // Refresh strip
  delay(20);                        // Pause 20 milliseconds (~50 FPS)

  getData();

  if (mode == 1)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < (60); i++)
    {
      if (i % 2 == 0)
        strip.setPixelColor(i, G, R, B);
    }
    strip.setBrightness(Bright);
    strip.show();
  }
  else
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < (60); i++)
    {
      if (i % 2 == 0)
        strip.setPixelColor(i, 150, 200, 40);
    }
    strip.setBrightness(255);
    strip.show();
  }
}

int readLine(int readch, char * buffer, int len)
{
  static int pos = 0;
  int rpos;

  if (readch > 0)
  {
    switch(readch)
    {
      case '\r':
      {
        break;
      }
      case '\n':
      {
        rpos = pos;
        pos = 0;
        return rpos;
      }
      default:
      {
        if (pos < len-1) 
        {
          buffer[pos++] = readch;
          buffer[pos] = 0;
        }
      }
  }

  return 0;
}
}

void getData()
{
  char buf[80];
  bool redo = true;

  if(readLine(Serial.read(), buf, 80) > 0)
  {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    bool skip = false;
    char fin[3];
    if (skip == false)
    {
    do//                                mode
    {
      switch (buf[i])
      {
        case '\n':
        {
          skip = true;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        case '|':
        {
          mode = atoi(fin);
          //Serial.print(mode);
          i++;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        default:
        {
          fin[j] = buf[i];
          i++;
          break;
        }
      }
      j++;
    }while(redo);
    redo = true;
    j = 0;
    }



    if (skip == false)
    {
    do//                     number of colors
    {
      switch (buf[i])
      {
        case '\n':
        {
          skip = true;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        case '|':
        {
          numColors = atoi(fin);
          //Serial.print(numColors);
          i++;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        default:
        {
          fin[j] = buf[i];
          i++;
          break;
        }
      }
      j++;
    }while(redo);
    redo = true;
    j = 0;
    }



    if (skip == false)
    {
    do//                            
    {
      switch (buf[i])
      {
        case '\n':
        {
          skip = true;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        case '|':
        {
          fadeSpeed = atoi(fin);
          //Serial.print(fadeSpeed);
          i++;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        default:
        {
          fin[j] = buf[i];
          i++;
          break;
        }
      }
      j++;
    }while(redo);
    redo = true;
    j = 0;
    }



    if (skip == false)
    {
    do
    {
      switch (buf[i])
      {
        case '\n':
        {
          skip = true;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        case '|':
        {
          BBCC = atoi(fin);
          //Serial.print(BBCC);
          i++;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        default:
        {
          fin[j] = buf[i];
          i++;
          break;
        }
      }
      j++;
    }while(redo);
    redo = true;
    j = 0;
    }



    if (skip == false)
    {
    do
    {
      switch (buf[i])
      {
        case '\n':
        {
          skip = true;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        case '|':
        {
          R = atoi(fin);
          //Serial.print(R);
          i++;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        default:
        {
          fin[j] = buf[i];
          i++;
          break;
        }
      }
      j++;
    }while(redo);
    redo = true;
    j = 0;
    }



    if (skip == false)
    {
    do
    {
      switch (buf[i])
      {
        case '\n':
        {
          skip = true;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        case '|':
        {
          G = atoi(fin);
          //Serial.print(G);
          i++;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        default:
        {
          fin[j] = buf[i];
          i++;
          break;
        }
      }
      j++;
    }while(redo);
    redo = true;
    j = 0;
    }



    if (skip == false)
    {
    do
    {
      switch (buf[i])
      {
        case '\n':
        {
          skip = true;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        case '|':
        {
          B = atoi(fin);
          //Serial.print(B);
          i++;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        default:
        {
          fin[j] = buf[i];
          i++;
          break;
        }
      }
      j++;
    }while(redo);
    redo = true;
    j = 0;
    }



    if (skip == false)
    {
    do
    {
      switch (buf[i])
      {
        case '\n':
        {
          Bright = atoi(fin);
          //Serial.println(Bright);
          i++;
          redo = false;
          break;
        }
        default:
        {
          fin[j] = buf[i];
          i++;
          break;
        }
      }
      j++;
    }while(redo);
    redo = true;
    j = 0;
    }
  }
}
```